# Should this question not be protected?

Tags: support

In my opinion [this question](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/2510/210) should be protected as this is a high valued one and the other answers hardly add any value.

Answer (score 2):

Protecting it would have prevented 2 answers out of 7, it has hit the Hot Network Question list and bring more views but not that much 'off scope' answers.

Maybe we'll add a post notice if it gather other answers repeating what's already said, but I don't really see a reason to protect it right now.